# set email used by php mail

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2

Is there a way I can set the email address used by php's `mail()` function without getting caught by spam filters?

If I don't add a from header the email is sent from `apache@ip-17....3.us-west-2.co....rnal` which isn't the worst name because most mail services just shorten to Apache.  But I would like to have that be `noreply.mydomain.com`  If I add a from header and put anything else it seems to always get caught by spam but not if just left to default.

My setup is PHP 7 on linux Amazon EC2 Micro

Comment: ok I acknoledge @John Conde's mark as duplicate and his link does match.  Should I delete the question or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use PHPMailer class at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer .

It allows you to use the mail function or use an smtp server transparently . It also handles HTML based emails and attachments so you don't have to write your own implementation.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```